# Simulate zero gravity style player movement

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am having a little trouble modelling the correct way to move my player node in the way
that I want.

This is my first foray into Spritekit and I have the basics up and running (I have a static background, added player node and have a playable bounds rectangle with bounds checking)

The way I have added my player movement is to track the beginning touch position and
store this in scene class scoped variable (Called beginningTouchPosition) and to also store the current touch position (Called currentTouchPosition).
I also track the players sprite node position (currentPlayerPosition)

What I do is onTouchesBegan I update 'beginningTouchPosition' and then within onTouchesMoved I update 'currentTouchPosition', this way I can know the direction the user wants his ship to move by getting the direction relative to the 'beginningTouchPosition' as he/she moves their finger around. Also the distance of 'currentTouchPosition' from 'beginningTouchPosition' determines how fast the ship moves.

I move the player in the update by creating a CGVector using the above points and using this with an SKAction.MoveBy call.

I did it this way as I wanted the user to be able to touch anywhere on the screen to be able to control movement.

How I wanted the player to move. I'd rather have the ship move by applying a certain set velocity with a set acceleration in a certain direction. So that the player will accelerate from zero to say 1 in the space of 1/2 second when the finger is moved and to continue in that direction until the finger is either moved again or lifted.

If the finger is lifted then the ship should continue moving in the last direction but to start decelerate until the velocity is back to zero.

I am basically trying to simulate how a object would move in zero gravity, with the obvious non-realistic feature of deceleration.

I've found tutorials that show how to move an object towards a finger touch but this isnt what I want as I am trying to make a game that is a side scrolling space shooter where the player can go anywhere within the playable area, as opposed to simply up and down. Similar to the old retro game 'Nemesis', see screen below:

[image: Nemesis]

I've attached my player class code and scene code for better visualization of how I am currently doing it all.

Any pointers to literature on how to apply velocities with acceleration in a specified direction would be helpful :)

## Scene file - Level_1.swift

```
import SpriteKit

// Global

/*
 Level_1 set up and control
 */
class Level_1: SKScene {
    // Instance variables
    var lastUpdateTime:NSTimeInterval = 0
    var dt:NSTimeInterval = 0
    var player = Player() // Sub classed SKSpriteNode for all player related stuff

    var currentTouchPosition: CGPoint!
    var beginningTouchPosition:CGPoint!
    var currentPlayerPosition: CGPoint!

    let playableRectArea:CGRect

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        // Constant - Max aspect ratio supported
        let maxAspectRatio:CGFloat = 16.0/9.0

        // Calculate playable height
        let playableHeight = size.width / maxAspectRatio

        // Determine margin on top and bottom by subtracting playable height 
        // from scene height and then divide by 2
        let playableMargin = (size.height-playableHeight)/2.0

        // Calculate the actual playable area rectangle
        playableRectArea = CGRect(x: 0, y: playableMargin,
                              width: size.width,
                              height: playableHeight)
        super.init(size: size)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        currentTouchPosition = CGPointZero
        beginningTouchPosition = CGPointZero

        let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background1")
        background.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
        background.zPosition = -1

        self.addChild(background)

        currentPlayerPosition = CGPoint(x: 100, y: size.height/2)

        player.position = currentPlayerPosition

        self.addChild(player)

    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            currentTouchPosition = touch.locationInNode(self)
        }

        let dxVectorValue = (-1) * (beginningTouchPosition.x - currentTouchPosition.x)
        let dyVectorValue = (-1) * (beginningTouchPosition.y - currentTouchPosition.y)

        player.movePlayerBy(dxVectorValue, dyVectorValue: dyVectorValue, duration: dt)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        player.removeAllActions()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            beginningTouchPosition = touch.locationInNode(self)
            currentTouchPosition = beginningTouchPosition
        }

    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
        currentPlayerPosition = player.position

        if lastUpdateTime > 0 {
            dt = currentTime - lastUpdateTime
        }else{
            dt = 0
        }
        lastUpdateTime = currentTime

        player.boundsCheckPlayer(playableRectArea)
    }
}
```

## Player node - Player.swift

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

struct PhysicsCategory {
    static let None         : UInt32 = 0
    static let All          : UInt32 = UInt32.max
    static let Player       : UInt32 = 0b1       // 1
    static let Enemy        : UInt32 = 0b10      // 2
}

class Player: SKSpriteNode{

    init(){

        // Initialize the player object
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ship1")

        super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: texture.size())

        self.xScale = 2
        self.yScale = 2
        self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        self.zPosition = 1

        // Player physics
        self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        self.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // Check if the player sprite is within the playable area bounds
    func boundsCheckPlayer(playableArea: CGRect){
        let bottomLeft = CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGRectGetMinY(playableArea))
        let topRight = CGPoint(x: playableArea.size.width, y: CGRectGetMaxY(playableArea))

        if(self.position.x <= bottomLeft.x){
            self.position.x = bottomLeft.x
            // velocity.x = -velocity.x
        }

        if(self.position.x >= topRight.x){
            self.position.x = topRight.x
            // velocity.x = -velocity.x
        }

        if(self.position.y <= bottomLeft.y){
            self.position.y = bottomLeft.y
            // velocity.y = -velocity.y
        }

        if(self.position.y >= topRight.y){
            self.position.y = topRight.y
            // velocity.y = -velocity.y
        }
    }

    /*
        Move the player in a certain direction by a specific amount
    */
    func movePlayerBy(dxVectorValue: CGFloat, dyVectorValue: CGFloat, duration: NSTimeInterval)->(){
        let moveActionVector = CGVectorMake(dxVectorValue, dyVectorValue)
        let movePlayerAction = SKAction.moveBy(moveActionVector, duration: 1/duration)
        self.runAction(movePlayerAction)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically we need a scene with zero gravity and a player where the touches cause force type physics actions. This is instead of moveBy type digital actions that simple move a character on the screen by such and such.

I went ahead and tested the code to try and get you something similar to what you describe. I altered some of your code a tad... to get it to work with my own set-up, as you didn't provide your GameViewController code so ask if you have any questions.

I've provided the code at the end with comments that say // IMPORTANT CODE with a # beside.

Here's details on why you use each piece of "IMPORTANT CODE

1. We need physics to accomplish what you describe so first ensure the player class will have a physics body. The body will be dynamic and affected by gravity (Zero Gravity), however you may want to fiddle with the gravity slightly for gameplay sake.

   ```
   let body:SKPhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, alphaThreshold: 0, size: texture.size() )

   self.physicsBody = body
   self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

   self.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
   self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
   ```
2. Since you want zero gravity we need to change our physics worlds gravity in our scene

   ```
     scene?.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
   ```
3. Next we change your movePlayerBy() to work with forces instead of simple digital movement. We do this with SKAction.applyForce.

This gives you a set-up based on force that's correlated with the swipe.
However, you may want a constant velocity no matter how hard the swipe. You can do that by normalizing the vector.. See here for somehow who asked that question and how it may apply here 
(http://www.scriptscoop2.com/t/adc37b4f2ea8/swift-giving-a-physicsbody-a-constant-force.html)

```
     func movePlayerBy(dxVectorValue: CGFloat, dyVectorValue: CGFloat, duration: NSTimeInterval)->(){

    print("move player")
    let moveActionVector = CGVectorMake(dxVectorValue, dyVectorValue)
    let movePlayerAction = SKAction.applyForce(moveActionVector, duration: 1/duration)
    self.runAction(movePlayerAction)
    }
```

4. If you want the player to decelerate , we must add a function to set the player's velocity to 0. I've made it so this happens 0.5 seconds after the function is initially called.. otherwise the "floating through gravity" effect isn't really noticed as the movement would end with touchesEnded().

You can experiment with other ways to de-accelerate like a negative force of what was used initially, before the pause action in the sequence below.

There's many other ways to make it more of a true deceleration ... like a second sequence that subtracts -1 from velocity at a set time interval until it hits 0, before we hard code velocity to 0.
But, that's up to you from a gameplay standpoint.

So this should be enough to give you an idea.

```
    func stopMoving() {
          let delayTime: NSTimeInterval = 0.5  // 0.5 second pause

          let stopAction: SKAction = SKAction.runBlock{
              self.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
           }

          let pause: SKAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(delayTime)

          let stopSequence: SKAction = SKAction.sequence([pause,stopAction])

          self.runAction(stopSequence)

     }
```

5. We alter touchesEnded() to call stopMoving()  .. But, try it without this to see it without that "deceleration".

   ```
   override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
         player.removeAllActions()

          player.stopMoving()
    }
   ```

Other Notes.

Currently the bounds only catch the player on the left and right with the code I created... I'm not sure if that will happen in your set-up. But, as that's another question to figure out, I didn't further look into it.

Here's my code I used ... I'm providing it since I made a few other minor alterations for the sake of testing. I wouldn't worry about anything other than where I place the new important pieces of code.

**GameScene.Swift**

```
import SpriteKit

// Global

/*
 Level_1 set up and control
 */


class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */



}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
}



class Level_1: GameScene {
// Instance variables
var lastUpdateTime:NSTimeInterval = 0
var dt:NSTimeInterval = 0
var player = Player() // Sub classed SKSpriteNode for all player related stuff

var currentTouchPosition: CGPoint  = CGPointZero
var beginningTouchPosition:CGPoint = CGPointZero
var currentPlayerPosition: CGPoint = CGPointZero

var playableRectArea:CGRect = CGRectZero


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    // IMPORTANT CODE 2 //

    scene?.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)

    // Constant - Max aspect ratio supported
    let maxAspectRatio:CGFloat = 16.0/9.0

    // Calculate playable height
    let playableHeight = size.width / maxAspectRatio

    // Determine margin on top and bottom by subtracting playable height
    // from scene height and then divide by 2
    let playableMargin = (size.height-playableHeight)/2.0


    // Calculate the actual playable area rectangle
    playableRectArea = CGRect(x: 0, y: playableMargin,
                              width: size.width,
                              height: playableHeight)

    currentTouchPosition = CGPointZero
    beginningTouchPosition = CGPointZero

    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Level1_Background")
    background.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
    background.zPosition = -1

    self.addChild(background)

    // CHANGED TO Put my own texture visible on the screen

    currentPlayerPosition = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)

    player.position = currentPlayerPosition

    self.addChild(player)

}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        currentTouchPosition = touch.locationInNode(self)
    }

    let dxVectorValue = (-1) * (beginningTouchPosition.x - currentTouchPosition.x)
    let dyVectorValue = (-1) * (beginningTouchPosition.y - currentTouchPosition.y)


    player.movePlayerBy(dxVectorValue, dyVectorValue: dyVectorValue, duration: dt)

}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    player.removeAllActions()

    // IMPORTANT CODE 5 //
    player.stopMoving()
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    print("touch")
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        beginningTouchPosition = touch.locationInNode(self)
        currentTouchPosition = beginningTouchPosition
    }

}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    currentPlayerPosition = player.position

    if lastUpdateTime > 0 {
        dt = currentTime - lastUpdateTime
    }else{
        dt = 0
    }
    lastUpdateTime = currentTime

    player.boundsCheckPlayer(playableRectArea)
}
}
```

**GameViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return .AllButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .All
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

**Player.swift**

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

struct PhysicsCategory {
    static let None         : UInt32 = 0
    static let All          : UInt32 = UInt32.max
    static let Player       : UInt32 = 0b1       // 1
    static let Enemy        : UInt32 = 0b10      // 2
}

class Player: SKSpriteNode{

init(){

    // Initialize the player object
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Player1")

    super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: texture.size())

    self.xScale = 2
    self.yScale = 2
    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    self.zPosition = 1

    // Player physics

    // IMPORTANT CODE 1 //

    let body:SKPhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, alphaThreshold: 0, size: texture.size() )

    self.physicsBody = body
    self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false



    self.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true

    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
}



required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {


    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}


// Check if the player sprite is within the playable area bounds
func boundsCheckPlayer(playableArea: CGRect){
    let bottomLeft = CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGRectGetMinY(playableArea))
    let topRight = CGPoint(x: playableArea.size.width, y: CGRectGetMaxY(playableArea))

    if(self.position.x <= bottomLeft.x){
        self.position.x = bottomLeft.x
        // velocity.x = -velocity.x
    }

    if(self.position.x >= topRight.x){
        self.position.x = topRight.x
        // velocity.x = -velocity.x
    }

    if(self.position.y <= bottomLeft.y){
        self.position.y = bottomLeft.y
        // velocity.y = -velocity.y
    }

    if(self.position.y >= topRight.y){
        self.position.y = topRight.y
        // velocity.y = -velocity.y
    }
}

/*
 Move the player in a certain direction by a specific amount
 */


// IMPORTANT CODE 3 //

func movePlayerBy(dxVectorValue: CGFloat, dyVectorValue: CGFloat, duration: NSTimeInterval)->(){

    print("move player")
    let moveActionVector = CGVectorMake(dxVectorValue, dyVectorValue)
    let movePlayerAction = SKAction.applyForce(moveActionVector, duration: 1/duration)
    self.runAction(movePlayerAction)
}

// IMPORTANT CODE 4 //

func stopMoving() {
    let delayTime: NSTimeInterval = 0.5  // 0.5 second pause

    let stopAction: SKAction = SKAction.runBlock{
        self.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
    }

    let pause: SKAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(delayTime)

    let stopSequence: SKAction = SKAction.sequence([pause,stopAction])

    self.runAction(stopSequence)

}

}
```

Comment: Hi Corey. Totally didnt expect your in depth how-to, I appreciate this immensly as it does explain a lot to me and works 1st try. I have not implemented the velocity part yet but will gt round to that later today. Thanks so much, appreciated.